# How to automate code signing with new rules after June 1 2023

Tags: azure-devops, automation, code-signing-certificate

We are using an old DV code signing certificate from Comodo for fully automated signing of the desktop .exe, .dll, and .msi files automatically in our Azure DevOps pipeline (we store the certificate in the Azure DevOps Library), but our certificate is going to expire soon.

Since June 1, 2023, there have been new requirements for the code signing certificates; for example, those can be provisioned only to a Hardware Security Module (HSM), so we could not just renew and upload to the Library again. Has anyone solved the renewal of the code signing certificate sing June 1? What is the best option to achieve fully automated builds?

I tried to renew the certificate at Comodo, but only a HW token option is available. I was investigating the Microsoft Azure Key Vault, but I am not sure which of the options we might need some of the services are quite expensive (for example, the HSM Pools for 3 USD / hour), and I am not sure what is needed.

Comment: SSL.com and DigiCert offer cloud-based signing services.  The DigiCert APIs seemed pretty thorough when I looked at them.  AWS has a cloud HSM service but it seems much less complete and their "what's new" was last updated in 2021.  Azure might have a cloud HSM offering but I don't use Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Microsoft Azure Key Vault. You do not need to use the HSM Pools and can just use the standard KeyVault but it does need to be on the Premium SKU. From what I can tell, the pricing is currently the same for Premium anyway.

It does take some setup to get all of the appropriate access in place to use the certificate but then you will use AzureSignTool instead of SignTool to access the certificate and sign your exe, dll, etc. It does not support as many file extensions as the old SignTool but seems to do most windows executables.

This [guide](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/code-signing-with-azure-devops/) is pretty useful for getting all of the correct access policies in place.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! 
I also like your other answer to the post [Is there any way to get a Code Signing certificate into Azure Key vault given the new FIPS requirement for storing the private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76579789/is-there-any-way-to-get-a-code-signing-certificate-into-azure-key-vault-given-th/76925226#76925226), where you share the details how to configure the Azure Key Vault and create a CSR.

Comment: Can this method be used to sign ClickOnce and MSIX apps?