# How do I sign an .app file with an Azure KeyVault stored certificate after June 2023?

Tags: azure-keyvault, code-signing-certificate, dynamics-business-central

Since June 1, 2023, there are [new requirements for a code signing certificates](https://knowledge.digicert.com/alerts/code-signing-changes-in-2023.html) that require HSM stored keys. For automation purposes, I am trying to use an Azure KeyVault stored certificate rather than the USB hardware token. This means that **.pfx files of code signing certificates are no longer available** for local installation of the certificate.

Because of this, I am looking for a way to use the Azure KeyVault stored certificate for code signing an `.app` file. The best option that I've been able to find so far is [AzureSignTool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureSignTool) as a replacement for the classic Microsoft [SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool).

I've managed to get the certificate ordered and installed in the [Azure KeyVault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76925226/22407382) and can use AzureSignTool to successfully sign standard windows executable files (.exe, .dll, .msi).

However, the AzureSignTool can not sign `.app` files because it's not a supported format. **Is there any workaround out there to either use the old SignTool + Azure KeyVault hosted cert or some other tool to use a cloud hosted (preferably Azure KeyVault) code signing certificate for signing `.app` files?**

AzureSignTool works correctly if signing an `.exe` but when trying a `.app` file, it returns the following error.

> The file cannot be signed because it is not a recognized file type for signing or it is corrupt.
> Signing failed with error 800B0003.

I've also tried using [AzuKI](https://github.com/namazso/AzuKI) to sign with the Microsoft SignTool connected to Azure KeyVault but get another error even with an exe file.

> SignTool Error: SignedCode::Sign returned error: 0x80070057
> The parameter is incorrect.